# Django and google charts

Tags: django, google-visualization

I need an advice how to prepare data for google charts API.
Lets say that I want to generate chart for user's transaction for last 7 days.
I want to count all Transaction model objects for this particular user since last week. How can I pass it to google chart URL? Any sugesstions?

Comment: Transactions for one user over a week would be a single number, how would you chart that? Are you thinking the chart would be across all users or transactions for one user over time?

Comment: I have models: Profile, Item, Transaction. Each Item has Profile assigned. Each Item may have multiple Transaction. I want to count all item's transactions but sliced properly to display as line chart.